# Basic MDCSelect not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, mdc-components

I can't get a basic select control working with MDC. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? (other mdc-components works just fine with on same setup)

[**UI-bug (PNG)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0evfo.png)

**Javascript**:

```
import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';
var selTEST = new MDCSelect(document.getElementById('selTEST'));
```

**CSS**:

```
@import "@material/select/mdc-select";
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="mdc-select" id="selTEST">
    <select class="mdc-select__native-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <option value="grains">Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta</option>
    <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
</select>
<label class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</label>
<div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
```